# Help with foreign key mapping in Hibernate (Spring)?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

I have the following two table (which are tied in with Spring security - but the issue I believe is with Hibernate):

```
Table user
Table authority
```

The `user` table is tied (through Hibernate) to a domain object in my application: `class User`, which has the following attributes (and corresponding getters and setters), which correspond to columns in the `user` table (except for the Collection which is explained later):

```
long uId
String username
String password
...
Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities
```

The `authority` table has 2 columns: `UserId` (foreign key into `user` table), and `Authority` (e.g. "ROLE_USER").  This table is NOT represented as a domain object, but is simply a collection in the `User` class.

To create the mapping, in my `.hbm` file I use the following:

```
<class name="com.business.project.domain.User" table="user">
    <id name="uId" column="UserId"></id>
    <property name="username" column="Name" type="java.lang.String" />
    <property name="password" column="Password" type="java.lang.String" />
    ...
    <set name="authorities" table="authority">
        <key column="UserId" />
        <element column="Authority" type="java.lang.String" />
    </set>
</class>
```

In my hibernate DAO implementation, I create a query object, execute the query, and cast the result to a `User` object:

```
...
Query query = session.createQuery("from User where name = :username");
...
User user = (User) query.uniqueResult();
```

At this point, I would expect this object to be populated with the data that it pulled from the DB (I made sure that the tables are populated properly with test data and the mapping names are correct in the mapping file).

However, calling the getter methods for various attributes on the `user` object all return `NULL` for some reason.  Can somebody see something immediately wrong with my setup?  Perhaps I mapped the collection (to foreign key relationship) wrong?  THANKS!

**Update**: here is the sql query that hibernate generated (taken from its DEBUG output):

```
Hibernate: select user0_.UserId as UserId1_, user0_.Name as Name1_, 
  user0_.Password as Password1_ from user user0_ where user0_.Name=?
```

For some reason, it doesn't show anything related to the `authority` table...does this mean that my mapping is incorrect?

**Edit**:  Per bozho's suggestion, I took a look at the messages on the consol on startup (tomcat), but didn't see anything out of the ordinary:

```
Feb 16, 2010 10:35:12 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
INFO: Mapping class: com.me.project.domain.User -> user
Feb 16, 2010 10:35:12 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollection
INFO: Mapping collection: com.me.project.domain.User.authorities -> authority
```

Comment: what versions of Spring Hibernate are you using . . . curious

Comment: Spring 3.0 and hibernate 3.2.7

Comment: The mapping looks ok to me and the association seems ok too but this is like groping in the dark. Can you provide the complete mapping and how you add your mapping to sessionfactory like spring config for example please? Are you able to save objects? Do you see them in your sql browser? If this is just a problem with the user entity i ld suggest to try reproduce it within a unit test w and wo the spring stuff.

Comment: Yes this is only a problem with the User entity (I have other mappings to other domain objects that get retrieved correctly).  I will try to dig more into this.  Thanks.

Comment: I think there should be more in the console about it. Perhaps during startup, when the mappings are realized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Query query = session.craeteQuery("FROM User WHERE username = :username");
query.setString("username", "SomeUserName");
```

That should pretty much do it.

Comment: I had this, I just didn't show the line.  The only difference is that I used the following: query.setString("username", username); where username is a parameter to the method.  I tried setParamter() just for fun and same problem.

Comment: System.out.println the value of the parameter to see what it is

Comment: yes, I have debug calls in that function that print out the value and its set properly (i.e. that value exists in the database).  Thakns for the suggestion.

Comment: did you try to manually execute the generated sql query with the real value of parameter (instead of `?`)? and what are the results.

Comment: just tried that, and it returns a row (fully populated) from the DB

Answer (score 0):

Try with `"from User where username = :username"`

HQL uses class properties, not db column names

Comment: same effect: everything is NULL.  I find this strange - wouldn't I have gotten some other error before if I was incorrectly using the column name in place of the class property?

Comment: when I change the name to something thats neither a class property nor a db column name, then I get an error.  Maybe hibernate is smart enough to check both class property and the db column to which its mapped?  Either way, my original issue is still there..

Comment: can your configure hibernate to log its sql queries? is there any real sql query was made?

Answer (score 0):

Are you clearing the database everytime you run the test/java code? In hibernate there is a setting and when it is turned on, it can clear the database everytime a test/java code is run.

Can you do a findAll() and print the size? I very much suspect it is the wrong db, or no data in the db or clearing of data.

NOTE: Check for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property in your config file. If it is set to "create-drop" hibernate will auto create the schema on startup and delete the schema when VM shuts down. Just point it to "update" or something

http://docs.atlassian.com/hibernate2/2.1.8/reference/session-configuration.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it and let you know.  But I'm skeptical because I always have a DB admin program open that shows me the data, and the data doesn't get cleared or anything.

Comment: Also just do a findAll, iterate through each user and print everything. You will know if you have missed something. Perhaps the "username" has a space in it that you are not giving, a space at the end...something :)

Comment: Still everything is NULL.  as I mentioned in a comment before, I tried querying the database directly with the query string that Hibernate generates (which I pulled from its debug output), and it properly returns the row...

Comment: Right so the findAll prints a number > 0. You pick the query "select user0_.UserId as UserId1_, user0_.Name as Name1_, 
  user0_.Password as Password1_ from user user0_ where user0_.Name=?" and run it against HQL DB and it shows a row with populated values.

But when you print username and password it shows up as null. Try to rename the columns to be x and y and see what happens (remember having problems with columns like username and password). Also make sure you have the getter/setter (although it is obvious)

Answer (score 0):

"Password" usually is a keyword in databases. It seems like you're hitting a name collision problem. Try the following. Put tick mark around the column name for escaping.

```
<property name="username" column="`Name`" type="java.lang.String" />
<property name="password" column="`Password`" type="java.lang.String" />
```

Assume you're using org.springframework.security.GrantedAuthority, then your mapping for authorities is incorrect. Based on the way you're mapping, when you access the collection, you  most likely will get a ClassCastException. You probably want to use something like UerType to avoid the problem.